# Sharepoint Online: How to unshare public links (AnonymousEdit/View links) via REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, roles

I'm looking to disable the Anonymous links created on my OneDrive for Business site through the [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx)
I used to delete the Roleassignments for Sharepoint\Reader... or Sharepoint\Writer... which used to disable those VIEW/EDIT links, but that's not anymore.
I am now getting special groups

> SharingLinks.sdasda-dq70-4310-b700-94e86e86ec9b.AnonymousView.ce5d848e-165d-463e-a240-f7ec53d1e58

and I am using them to identify that my File's Edit/View link was created.

For disabling the link through REST API I did a POST with X-Http-Method as Delete and it removed the group as well. But the link stayed as is. Only when I disabled it through the UI then I noticed that a special user was unshared

> c:0u.c|tenant|00468b2d8e1f4d4255875c0ddb5ebab20f7561e62968d7e3e936180b219cb036

this strange looking Title/LoginName has *RoleTypeKind* as 255. What exactly does 255 mean?
I tried to rely on these special users for the identification of a Public exposure but they don't indicate anything about the type of Public Link they refer to.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [Web.DeleteAnonymousLinkForObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.deleteanonymouslinkforobject.aspx) method to remove/unshare the link for anon users.

Code would be somewhat as below:

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.Web.DeleteAnonymousLinkForObject";
      console.log(url);
      $.ajax(
      {
          'url': url,
          'method': 'POST',
          'data': JSON.stringify({
             'url': _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/Shared Documents/test.txt',
             'isEditLink': true,
             'removeAssociatedSharingLinkGroup':true
          }),
          'headers': {
          'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
          'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
          'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
          },
          'success': function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log("Success");
                //console.log(data.d.DeleteAnonymousLinkForObject);
          },
          'error': function (err) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
           }
      }
      );
     }
```

Comment: is there any URL where they notify such changes in the API?

Comment: I took reference of this blog - http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.in/2016_01_01_archive.html, but you can get updates froms Office blogs as well where they release almost monthly updates of CSOM API